# DB2 Command to export table data in to a file

Tags: database, db2, export, ascii

In DB2, I would like to export table data into a file and my output should be ASCII delimited file.

Answer (score 2):

The [IBM manuals](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0008303.htm) for DB2 version 9 describe all of the commands you can use in DB2.  The command you're looking for is DB2 EXPORT.